# page.getViewById only works when called on page load

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to use `page.getViewById(idName).text` to get the text input into a text field, but it's not going so well.

If I use it within the `pageLoaded` function, called on page load, it works just fine.

If I call a function using `<Button text="Update" tap="functionName" />`, I get `ReferenceError: page is not defined`.

If I instead call `pageLoaded` a second time (this isn't what I want to do but for troubleshooting purposes it was worth a shot), I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`.

How can I access a component's properties after the page has been initially loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to define page, such as,

```
const button = args.object;
const page = button.page;
```

Comment: Not the exact same scenario, but pretty much the same issue that I'm still having trouble with. I'm calling a function which adds children to a component, but it's just silently terminating. I'm passing `args` to the function and have `const page = args.object.page` at the top of the function but that's not helping.

Comment: To clarify, the page stuff can be accessed. If I do `console.log(page.getViewById("..."))` within the function, some details are returned. But `page.getViewById("...").addChild(...)` will fail, even though it works in the very same function if called during the initial `loaded` event.

Comment: Have you tried putting that code in try/catch block to catch any error message?